# Angular-CLI TestComponentBuilder.createAsync() not resolve its promise

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular-cli

I have created a very simple sample test for a project based on angular-cli. The problem, as you can see from the title is that for a reason the TestComponentBuilder.createAsync() does not resolve its promise. Here is my code. I suspect that the problem is in the karma-test-shim.js config file, but I'm not sure about this. The result of the test is always success though I have set this "expect(true).toEqual(false)" for my test. I'm working with Angular 2-RC4

```
import {
beforeEach,
beforeEachProviders,
describe,
expect,
it,
inject
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ComponentFixture, TestComponentBuilder } from    '@angular/core/testing';

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

describe('Component: CollectionCounterWidgetComponent', () => {

let builder: TestComponentBuilder;
beforeEach(inject([TestComponentBuilder], function (tcb:  TestComponentBuilder) {
builder = tcb;
}));

it('should create the CollectionCounterWidgetComponent component',  inject([], () => {
return builder.createAsync(ComponentTestController)
  .then((fixture: ComponentFixture<any>) => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(true).toEqual(false);
  });

}));
});

@Component({
selector: 'test',
template: `
<h1>why?</h1>
`
})
class ComponentTestController {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular 2 RC4 you need to wrap the `inject` function your asynchronous test with `async`. This runs your test in an `AsyncTestZoneSpec` and makes sure that all asynchronous calls within this zone are done.

In your case you should `import {async} from '@angular/core/testing'` and modify your test:

```js
it('should create the CollectionCounterWidgetComponent component', async( inject([], () => {

     builder.createAsync(TestControllerComponent)
      .then((fixture: ComponentFixture<any>) => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(true).toEqual(false);
      });

    }))
);
```

Now your test will fail as expected. Also you don't need a return statement (e.g. return builder...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok michael, you are right, this was my fault, but the problem remains. I have created another project with angular-cli just to have a clean project to work with and I created the following very simple test.

```
import {
async,
inject,
describe,
it,
expect,
TestComponentBuilder,
ComponentFixture
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component' ;

describe('Component: AppComponent', () => {

it('should create an instance', async(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
  tcb.createAsync(AppComponent)
  .then(fixture => {
    expect(true).toBe(false);
  })
 })));
});
```

But the execution of the test is successful. I have to mention that by default angular-cli uses RC3 in the current version and I have updated the version of angular to RC4. I tested the above test in the same project with "injectAsync" instead of "async(inject.." and angular RC3 and is working properly in this case. Thanks